# Formatting in a JTextfield

Tags: java, swing, format, string-formatting, jtextfield

When I do this:-

```
GUI.this.libraryResult.setText(String.format("%-30s%-30s%-20s%-20s%n","\tTITLE","AUTHOR","YEAR","ISBN"));
for (Book book : booklist) {
    GUI.this.libraryResult.setText(libraryResult.getText() + String.format ("%-30s%-30s%-20s%-20s%n",
            "\t" + book.getTitle(), book.getAuthor(), book.getYear(), book.getISBN()));
```

I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong that is stopping them justifying left properly?

Comment: *"I get this:"* Not in a `JTextField`. A text **field** will only display a single line of data. That might be a `JTextArea`. Please be careful when identifying classes. Or better. post a [mre] where the reader can verify the class type themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the text area is using a variable width font (where an **I** will take up less width than a **W**). Use a `Font.MONOSPACED` to fix the immediate problem.

More generally though, this is tabular data. A `JTable` was *designed* for just this purpose! More importantly, it offers many handy features, like the ability to sort or filter the table, or use different formatting for different columns (e.g. making the Title/Author *italic*) and values in a column (e.g. giving the Year a darker color by decade).